# Adding Bootstrap JavaScript to Docusaurus but having issues

Tags: javascript, docusaurus

Got the JavaScript in the head of the document. Great.

BUT the bootstrap components I'm rendering in Docusaurus, whilst styled correctly, aren't affected by the Bootstrap minified file I'm importing into the project. It needs to be put in the footer and I've been banging my head against the wall.

Do I need to add `Bootstrap` as a plugin to get it working? So dropdowns etc are working etc.

Any help or guidance greatly appreciated!

Kind regards,

Kurtis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the bar-steward!

https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/lifecycle-apis/#injecthtmltags

Goes to show that "reading the docs" really can help when Google fails

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question. But in general, getting your Javascript to run at the right time was a challenge for me too. I documented a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74736980/202292

Comment: Hi Jeff, I think the page I initially shared has changed and they're redirecting off to somewhere else, glad you sorted and thanks for sharing your solution  I used Docusaurus V2 for a production build when it was in beta - not my best moment - it worked out but I wouldn't want to be the one updating it